# org.apache.http.client.HttpClient conflict with Android Plateform

Tags: conflict, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

Android 4.4.2 has old version of `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` but I want to use new version of `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`that I have added through jar.

How to force Android to use `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` from jar rather than from framework itself.

I am creating a client using this

```
this.mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(
                    mCtx.getApplicationContext(), new HttpClientStack(HttpClientBuilder.create().build()));
```

and since it is importing `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` from framework (that is old version) it is throwing me following exception

```
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527): Process: com.az, PID: 24527
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:494)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.beusoft.app.VolleySingleton.getRequestQueue(VolleySingleton.java:39)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.beusoft.app.VolleySingleton.<init>(VolleySingleton.java:27)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.beusoft.app.VolleySingleton.getInstance(VolleySingleton.java:32)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.beusoft.app.AppContext.onCreate(AppContext.java:101)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-23 18:15:42.252: E/AndroidRuntime(24527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**How to force Android to use `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` from library instead framework version.**

Answer (score 1):

You just can't.

You have two options essentially:

1. repackage HttpClient to a different namespace

org.apache.http -> thank.you.google.org.apache.http

2. use official HttpClient Android port, which is fully API compatible with Android but only partially compatible with the stock version of HC. For more details please see this [resource](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

Comment: I love that thank.you.google.org :-) Well dear renaming is not an option for me because I am using multiple Apache Libraries that will make the code really unstable :-/. I'll look into the resource. Thanks